# Merge and replace elements of two dataframes using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data-frames:

DF1:

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═════════╦════╗
║ Name  ║ Age ║ Address ║ Id ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test1 ║ 20  ║  ls     ║ 10 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test2 ║     ║ baz     ║ 15 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test3 ║     ║ az      ║ 19 ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═════════╩════╝
```

DF2 :

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═════════╦════╗
║ Name  ║ Age ║ Address ║ Id ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test4 ║ 20  ║ bas     ║ 10 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test5 ║     ║ baz     ║ 25 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test6 ║ 40  ║ az      ║ 19 ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═════════╩════╝
```

Result :

```
╔═══════╦═════╦═════════╦════╗
║ Name  ║ Age ║ Address ║ Id ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test1 ║ 20  ║ ls      ║ 10 ║
╠═══════╬═════╬═════════╬════╣
║ test2 ║ 40  ║  az     ║ 19 ║
╚═══════╩═════╩═════════╩════╝
```

What I want to achieve : 
 1.when Id matches in both the frames it should consider only that record in output. 
 2. All the columns of that matching record should be replaced by DF1 columns.
 3. If DF1 Column is empty and data is present in DF2 then it should not replace it.

Tried Joins as well:

```
DF3 = DF1.join(DF2, [DF1.Id == DF2.Id], 'inner')
DF3.show()
```

Result:

```
Name,Age,Adress,Id,Name,Age,Adress,Id
test1,20,ls,10,test5,20,bas,10
```

If I use

```
DF3 = DF1.join(DF2, [DF1.Id == DF2.Id], 'leftsemi')
DF3.show()
```

It gives me data from DF1 and do not add missing values from D2.

Trying to achieve below :

```
for i in df2.columns:
    df2 = df2.withColumn(i, when(df1.Id == col("Id") & (col(i) == ""), df1(i)).otherwise(col(i)))
df2.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Outer Join will keep records from both the tables along with the associated null values in the respective left/right tables. Data from left and right can be compared (check if null) and replace with not-null values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

ds1 = [
    {'Name': 'test1', 'Age': 20, 'Address': 'ls', 'Id': 10},
    {'Name': 'test2', 'Age': None, 'Address': 'baz', 'Id': 15},
    {'Name': 'test3', 'Age': None, 'Address': 'az', 'Id': 19},
]

ds2 = [
    {'Name': 'test4', 'Age': 20, 'Address': 'az', 'Id': 10},
    {'Name': 'test5', 'Age': None, 'Address': 'az', 'Id': 25},
    {'Name': 'test6', 'Age': 40, 'Address': 'az', 'Id': 19},
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(ds1)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(ds2)

df1.show()

+-------+----+---+-----+
|Address| Age| Id| Name|
+-------+----+---+-----+
|     ls|  20| 10|test1|
|    baz|null| 15|test2|
|     az|null| 19|test3|
+-------+----+---+-----+

df2.show()

+-------+----+---+-----+
|Address| Age| Id| Name|
+-------+----+---+-----+
|     az|  20| 10|test4|
|     az|null| 25|test5|
|     az|  40| 19|test6|
+-------+----+---+-----+

join_by_col = 'Id'

df_ = df1.join(df2, on=[join_by_col], how='outer').orderBy(join_by_col)

df_.show()

+---+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+
| Id|Address| Age| Name|Address| Age| Name|
+---+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+
| 10|     ls|  20|test1|     az|  20|test4|
| 15|    baz|null|test2|   null|null| null|
| 19|     az|null|test3|     az|  40|test6|
| 25|   null|null| null|     az|null|test5|
+---+-------+----+-----+-------+----+-----+

for col in df1.columns:
    if col != join_by_col:
        col_ = col + '_'
        df_ = df_.withColumn(
            col_, when(df1[col].isNull(), df2[col]).otherwise(df1[col])).drop(col)

df_.show()

+---+--------+----+-----+
| Id|Address_|Age_|Name_|
+---+--------+----+-----+
| 10|      ls|  20|test1|
| 15|     baz|null|test2|
| 19|      az|  40|test3|
| 25|      az|null|test5|
+---+--------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help, it doesn't fit with my requirement column should be unique + when number of record increases unnecessarily number of headers will load in  the memory